# Ubuntu 16.04 mean.js installation (without using one click app on digitalocean)

Tags: gruntjs, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, meanjs, nvm

I am trying to install mean.js on my ubuntu 16.04 using the following guide. And I keep getting stuck at the grunt stage.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

There were issues with building node so I install using nvm

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04#how-to-install-using-nvm

Then there were issues with bower where the process was killed. Managed to solved that by adding swap. I have the 512 MB ram settings.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Now my problem is grunt. I now have this error.

```
    /opt/mean$ grunt
    A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for more information on how to configure    grunt:\http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
    Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.
```

Then when I tried

```
    /opt/mean$ npm install
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /opt/mean/nodemodules/tiny-lr/nodemodules
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /opt/mean/nodemodules/tiny-lr/nodemodules/body-parser/nodemodules
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /opt/mean/nodemodules/tiny-lr/nodemodules/raw-body/nodemodules
    npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@6.0.2 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
    npm ERR! path /opt/mean/nodemodules/tiny-lr/nodemodules
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall access
    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/mean/nodemodules/tiny-lr/nodemodules'
    npm ERR! at Error (native)
    npm ERR! { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/mean/nodemodules/tiny-lr/nodemodules'
    npm ERR! at Error (native)
    npm ERR! errno: -13,
    npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR! syscall: 'access',
    npm ERR! path: '/opt/mean/nodemodules/tiny-lr/nodemodules' }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR! /home/ktyc/.npm/logs/2017-06-17T084313072Z-debug.log
```

This is my second droplet try.

If anyone need me to edit the question or require more information, just leave a message.

Comment: why don't you want to use the 1-click install image?

Comment: I want to start by learning how to install it.

Comment: After I execute `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf` and comment `#security:
#  authorization: "enabled"` The mongo error go away.

I didn't really solved the problem but the mean.js test page loads.

More details here [Questions in DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubuntu-16-04-mean-js-installation-without-using-one-click-app)